# Problemas para imprimir valores de un vector de objetos en reversa

Tags: c++

Teniendo la siguiente clase;

```
class Estudiante {

private:
    string nombre,cedula;
    int matricula;
    float calificacion;

public:
    //se dejo con un destructor por defecto
    void anadir(int _matricula,string _nombre,string _cedula,float _calificacion);
    void insertar();
    void borrar();
    void listar();
    void listar_inverso();
    void promedio();
    int getMatricula() const {
        return matricula;
    }
    float getCalificacion() const {
        return calificacion;
    }

};
/**
* Este metodo es utilizado para asignarle los datos a cada una de las propiedades
* de esta manera el objeto con todas sus propiedades asignadas se almacenan
* en el vector de estudiantes
**/
void Estudiante::anadir(int _matricula,string _nombre,string _cedula,float _calificacion) {
    matricula = _matricula;
    nombre = _nombre;
    cedula = _cedula;
    calificacion = _calificacion;
}
/**
* Lista los estudiantes, es utilizado por el vecto junto a un
* iterador
**/
void Estudiante::listar() {
    cout << matricula <<" "  << nombre <<" " << cedula <<" " << calificacion << endl;

}
```

creo objetos de tipo estudiantes para guardarlos en un vector del tipo de la clase `Estudiante`;

`main`

```
//Creando un vector de tipo estudiante
    vector<Estudiante> lista_estudiantes;

    Estudiante *est;
    //Nuevo objeto de tipo estudiante
    est = new Estudiante;
    est->anadir("10020098","Albert Hidalgo","000-0000000-0","99");
    lista_estudiantes.push_back(*est);
    est->anadir("10330066","Abimael Hidalgo","000-0000000-0","100");
    lista_estudiantes.push_back(*est);
```

Hasta aquí todo perfecto, ahora bien si pretendo imprimir lo que ya he registrado en reversa, osea que el ultimo registro del vector salga arriba en una impresión obtengo la siguiente salida;

```
//Imprimiendo los datos
vector<Estudiante>::iterator itInverso;
for ( itInverso = lista_estudiantes.end(); itInverso != lista_estudiantes.begin(); --itInverso )
    itInverso->listar();
//Salida
MATRICULA | NOMBRE        |     CEDULA      | CALIFICACION
0             *                    *             0
10020098   Abimael Hidalgo   000-0000000-0      100
```

Me obvia el primer registro y en vez de esto me imprime un objeto vació o en otros casos también me termina la ejecución del programa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto lo resolví restando 1 a los `ireradores` con los metodos `end()` y `begin()`en el ciclo for;

```
vector<Estudiante>::iterator itInverso;
for ( itInverso = (lista_estudiantes.end() - 1); itInverso != (lista_estudiantes.begin()- 1); --itInverso )
       itInverso->listar();
```

Y ya obtengo una salida valida;

```
MATRICULA | NOMBRE        |     CEDULA      | CALIFICACION
10020098   Abimael Hidalgo   000-0000000-0      100
10020098   Albert Hidalgo    000-0000000-0      99
```

Answer (score 5):

Para recorrer los contenedores del revés, empezando por el último elemento y terminando por el primero, puede usar los `reverse-iterator`:

```
for( auto itInverso = vector.crbegin( ); itInverso != vector.crend( ); ++itInverso ) {
  itInverso->listar();
}
```

El principal *inconveniente* de su uso es que no se pueden usar con los `range-based for` de C++11.

Answer (score 3):

¿Por qué la clase `Estudiante` tiene métodos como `anadir`, `borrar`, `listar`, etc...? ¿Qué añade, borra o lista un estudiante? Creo que tienes algunos conceptos liados.

Por lo que parece, la clase `Estudiante` describe a un estudiante, así pues no tiene sentido dotarla de ningún tipo de gestión de datos (eso sería para una clase que almacenase estudiante**s**). Cambia la clase de manera acorde:

```
class Estudiante {

    string nombre,cedula;
    int matricula;
    float calificacion;

    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &, const Estudiante &);
public:
    Estudiante(int _matricula, string _nombre, string _cedula, float _calificacion) :
        nombre(_nombre),
        cedula(_cedula),
        matricula(_matricula),
        calificacion(_calificacion)
    {}
    int getMatricula() const {
        return matricula;
    }
    float getCalificacion() const {
        return calificacion;
    }
};

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Estudiante &e) {
    return o << e.matricula << " "  << e.nombre << " " << e.cedula << " " << e. calificacion << '\n';
}
```

De esta manera, al añadir estudiantes a tu `vector<Estudiante>`, puedes construirlos dentro del mismo ahorrándote copias:

```
// Creando un vector de tipo estudiante
vector<Estudiante> vector_estudiantes;

// Nuevo objeto de tipo estudiante creado directamente en el vector
vector_estudiantes.emplace_back("10020098", "Albert Hidalgo",  "000-0000000-0", "99");
// Nuevo objeto de tipo estudiante creado directamente en el vector
vector_estudiantes.emplace_back("10330066", "Abimael Hidalgo", "000-0000000-0", "100");
```

Para recorrer los elementos de un contenedor en sentido inverso, usa los iteradores inversos [*reverse begin* [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) y [*reverse end* [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend):

```
for (auto b = vector_estudiantes.rbegin(), e = vector_estudiantes.rend(), b != e; ++b)
{
    std::cout << *b;
}
```

Comment: Se que no esta del todo correcto, los maestro de las universidades piden cosas que honestamente no tienen sentido y violan muchos principios.